# This "measure" of a set is equal to the Lebesgue measure of the set's interior

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The "measure" I am referring to is similar to the inner Jordan measure, and defined as:

$m^{**}(A) = \sup\{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ell(I_n) : (I_n)$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint open intervals with $\cup_{n=1}^{N}I_n \subseteq A \}$

> Prove that $m^{**}(A) = m(A^{\circ})$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue
>   measure and $A^{\circ}$ is the interior of A.

Intuitively, it makes sense why this is true. However, I cannot figure out how to show it rigorously. Here is what I have so far:

**If A is open**:

$m^{**}(A)$

$= \sup\{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ell(I_n) : (I_n)$ finite seq. of pairwise disjoint open intervals, $\cup_{n=1}^{N}I_n \subseteq A \}$

$= \inf\{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\ell(I_n) : (I_n)$ finite seq. of pairwise disjoint open intervals, $A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{N}I_n  \} $

$\geq m(A)$

$ = m(A^{\circ})$

But obviously this isn't the full proof for that particular case, let alone considering all cases.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that open subsets of R are countable disjoint unions of closed intervals?

Comment: are you allowed to use the fact that Lebesgue measure is inner regular?